# Cannot create a user in Voyager (laravel 6.x)

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed the admin package Voyager (without dummy data) on my Laravel project and when I want to create a user to access the admin panel with the following command: `php artisan voyager:admin admin@admin.com --create`, I get the following error:

[image]

After a little bit of searching, I found this link: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/5082 => saying that this command does not work with PHP 7.4 and to make it work, I should either upgrade to PHP 7.4.1 or downgrade to PHP 7.3.

I'm using Wamp Server and decided to downgrade to PHP 7.3.12 since this version exists by default in C:\wamp64\bin\php
I have also edited composer.lock and composer.json in my project and then ran the command **composer dump-autoload**. But it still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, upgraded to php 7.4.27 and it worked.